# How to set up mx records

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record, reverse-dns, email-bounces

So I bought a new domain name from GoDaddy and pointed the domain to my VPS IP Address which works fine.

[Please note, the VPS is not hosted with GoDaddy, just the domain name.]

However, I noticed that all incoming mails from external servers (gmail, yahoomail, other domains, etc) keep bouncing back even though outcoming emails (from my domain to other mail servers work fine).

After googling the issue out, it seems that I need to make changes to my domain's MX Records in order to be able to send/receive mail.

In GoDaddy, the mx records are as follows:

```
10  @   mailstore1.secureserver.net 1 Hour  
0   @   smtp.secureserver.net   1 Hour
```

### What I have tried so far:

1. So as instructed by online tutorials and forums, I created an A Record `mail.abcd.com` and pointed it to my VPS IP Address.
2. After that, I added this line to the list of MX Records:

   `1 @ mail.abcd.com 1 hour`

So now it looks like this:

```
10  @   mailstore1.secureserver.net 1 Hour  
0   @   smtp.secureserver.net   1 Hour
1   @   mail.abcd.com   1 Hour
```

[I have replaced my domain with `abcd.com` in the above snippet]

However, I still can't send anything to any email hosted in my server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the output of dig MX abcd.com ? and are there A records for mail.abcd.com and other MX records ?

Comment: @Lazy404 Should I run that on SSH or somewhere else?

Comment: any linux box with dig installed will do

Comment: I get this:

abcd.com.  3599 IN MX 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
abcd.com.  3599 IN MX 0 smtp.secureserver.net.
abcd.com.  3599 IN MX 1 mail.abcd.com.

Comment: Copied the result here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/126/

Comment: If `abcd.com` is your idea of a sensibly-redacted domain name, please (a) read [our guide on what and how to redact](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts), and (b) give us the real domain name.

Comment: @MadHatter Domain name info updated.

Comment: Thank you for that, but you still haven't told us *your* domain name - the most important piece of information.  Is it `shillong.work`?

Comment: Oh and yes, I'm using the latest cPanel/WHM on the VPS if that makes any difference.

Comment: Let's overlook the cpanel thing for a moment, since that is pretty much grounds for closing the question all by itself.  Which of the many servers you've listed in your `MX` is your shiny new mail server, the one to which you want the internet to send email for `shillong.work`?  Is it `mail.shillong.work`, aka `server.khublei.com`?

Comment: You mean the vps IP that I'm pointing `mail.shillong.work` to? It's `173.254.231.119`

Comment: What's the exact content of bounce message ?

Comment: I got this: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/127/

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my theory that mail's being handed off to `smtp.secureserver.net`, which doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: See MadHatter's answer. Your mail is getting delivered to the wrong server. You should remove the two ".secureserver.net" MX records for your domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have other servers than your mail server listed in your `MX` record, one of which has a lower priority.  `MX` records work on a lowest-priority-first basis, which means the internet is first of all trying to send mail for your domain to `smtp.secureserver.net.`, which doesn't seem to know anything about your domain.  At this point, delivery fails fatally, and there's an end of it; your server, being listed at second priority, will never get tried.

The only mail servers you should list in your `MX` records are those that **either** (a) are prepared to accept email for your domain, for final delivery, **or** (b) are prepared to accept email for your domain with a view to delivering it on to a final delivery server, *and* are specifically configured to do so.

If you overhaul the `MX` record for `shillong.work` to something like

```
shillong.work.          3600    IN      MX      10 mail.shillong.work.
```

and remove all other `MX` records, then wait an hour (for the 3600s TTL to expire), the internet should start delivering your inbound mail to your server.